# Why does this keep saying object-defined error?

Tags: excel, vba

I've been stuck on this for hours so would really appreciate the help.
For aa you are supposed to select a range in another workbook to use as a reference.
The .Cells(11, 3).Formula = line won't stop coming up with object-defined error. Please could I have some help on what is wrong with my formula?
If I just do .Cells(11, 3).Formula = "text" it works, but I need it to be the formula...

```
Dim aa As Range
Dim bb As Range
Dim cc As Range

Set aa = Application.InputBox("", Type:=8)
Set bb = Application.InputBox("", Type:=8)
Set cc = Application.InputBox("", Type:=8)


.Cells(11, 3).Formula = "=INDEX(" & aa.Address(External:=True) & ",MATCH(1,($E11=" & bb.Address(External:=True) & "*(F$9=" & cc.Address(External:=True) & ",0))"
```

Comment: Your code has 4 `(` but only 2 `)`

Comment: Excel doesn't let you write an invalid formula into a cell, neither manually nor via code. When trying to write an invalid formula into a cell, you will get that exact error. Hint: Don't write a formula directly into a cell. Write it into an intermediate variable and dump that into the immediate window. With that it's much easier to check the formula you try to write.

Comment: You use `.Cells`... but no `with` before that (unless there is code missing, in which case, please edit your question to include it). Try `ActiveSheet.Cells`...